# Opening a Json File From Google API's In Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I would like to open a json file in python as an object that I can manipulate and work with

I have a json file than contains text like the following

```
{'geocoded_waypoints': [{'geocoder_status': 'OK', 'place_id': 'ChIJtxsqpbgEdkgRSCY1a5fQpDA', 'types': ['airport', 'establishment', 'point_of_interest']}, {'geocoder_status': 'OK', 'place_id': 'ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}], 'routes': ......
```

...

I received this json text from the google transit api, [I know that json doesn't look like the above text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491420/python-jsonexpecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes/39491613), but that's what google transit gives me so thats what I have to work with.

I've tried [this method](http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-xml-json/),

```
>>> data = json.load(open('gmap_routes.json'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

And [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file) where I tried to fix the unicode characters in it but it would not work

```
>>> import json
>>> with open("gmap_routes.json") as f:
...     json.load(f.encode("ascii","replace"))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I also tried python2 for a while and got similar results, so I just went back to python3

Comment: This is bad json. There is a [package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855065/229602) that can deal with it. I suspect that there is an issue with how you're obtaining the data though. A google API shouldn't give you malformed JSON.

Comment: `encode` is a method for unicode objects, and I cannot see in your code `f ` declaration. Maybe you could try to load json in an object, cast to an unicode, and then execute encode.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, those "'" characters are the problem.

You'll need to perform a replace operation on the contents of the file by calling file.read(), not the file itself - this will return a string so use json.loads instead of json.load on the result:

```
    import json
    file = open("some_file.json")
    with file as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read().replace("'", "\""))
```

Comment: For me, this returns the same error as the first method `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`