# Python - Invalid JSON format - how to parse

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting data in the following JSON format:

```
{
  address:[
    "test1"
  ],
  city:"test2",
  country:"test3",
  postal_code:"test4",
  state:"test5"
}
```

While I am trying to parse it via:

```
json.loads(data)
```

I am receiving an error: *Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes*

Is there a way to parse it in python ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The double quotes are missing, for address, city and other fields. refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491420/python-jsonexpecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It goes without saying that the better solution would be to fix the broken data at the source. But if you can't do that, you could try and fix the problem with a simple regex. Simple, as in "will fail if you throw anything more complicated at it", but likely sufficient as a quick and dirty solution:

```
import re
import json
with open("almost.json") as infile:
    jstring = infile.read()
data = json.loads(re.sub(r"(\w+):", r'"\1":', jstring))
```

Answer (score 6):

The json standard needs the key with `""`, so you can't decode data with json module.
However, you can do it with `demjson` (`pip install demjson`).

```py
demjson.decode(data)
```

Comment: This answer works well. I use `demjson` to parse any JSON that yields a json.JSONDecodeError with the normal decoder.

Answer (score 2):

Your variables should be like "address" or "city".

```
{
  "address":[
    "test1"
  ],
  "city":"test2",
  "country":"test3",
  "postal_code":"test4",
  "state":"test5"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json5`. JSON5 extends the JSON data interchange format to make it slightly more usable.

```
import json5
JsonStr = """{
  address:[
    "test1"
  ],
  city:"test2",
  country:"test3",
  postal_code:"test4",
  state:"test5"
}"""

json5.loads(JsonStr)
```

out:

```
{'address': ['test1'],
 'city': 'test2',
 'country': 'test3',
 'postal_code': 'test4',
 'state': 'test5'}
```

Answer (score -1):

'''''''

```
{
  "address":[
  "test1"
  ],
"city":"test2",
"country":"test3",
"postal_code":"test4",
"state":"test5"
```

}

''''

Please change your code format to this , it will works

Comment: This is essentially the same answer posted by Türker Berke Yıldırım 4 years ago.