# Malformed json fixing in pyspakr

Tags: json, pyspark, malformed

I have a json file which i recieved from source in below format.
{
"api_version": "1.3",
"response_code": "200",
"id": "3237490513229753",
"lon": "38.969916127827",
"lat": "45.069889625267",
"page_url": null,
"name": "ATB",
"firm_group": {
"id": "3237499103085728",
"count": "1"
},
"city_name": "Krasnodar",
"city_id": "3237585002430511",
"address": "Turgeneva,   172/1",
"create_time": "2008-07-22 10:02:04 07",
"modification_time": "2013-08-09 20:04:36 07",
"see_also": [
{
"id": "3237491513434577",
"lon": 38.973110606808,
"lat": 45.029031222211,
"name": "Advance",
"hash": "5698hn745A8IJ1H86177uvgn94521J3464he26763737242Cf6e654G62J0I7878e",
"ads": {
"sponsored_article": {
"title:"aman",
"text": "Business.English."
},
"warning": null
}
}
]
}
I know there is syntax issue in title key not enclosed in double quotes.How can I fix this basic syntax issues of json file automatically? Any help will be much apprecited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Invalid JSON format - how to parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355495/python-invalid-json-format-how-to-parse)

Comment: @Joe  I am getting below error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_parser.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.loads(re.sub(r"(\w+):", r'"\1":', jstring))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 16 column 33 (char 403)

Comment: Below is the code.

Comment: import re
import json
with open("/home/ec2-user/environment/test2.json") as infile:
    jstring = infile.read()
data = json.loads(re.sub(r"(\w+):", r'"\1":', jstring))
print(data)