# How to read with pandas a set of arrays containing one JSON object each?

Tags: json, pandas

I am trying to read from a text file into a pandas dataframe. The text file seems to be a 2D array of JSON, how could I read it?

[[{'metric_name':'CPU','category':'A','data':'9','time_stamp':'2019-03-28 13:15:31'}],[{'metric_name':'Disk','category':'B','data':'56','time_stamp':'2019-03-28 13:15:31'}]]

I expect to have the parameters "metric_name", "category", "data", "time_stamp" as headers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :

```
import json
import pandas as pd

# load the file
raw_data = json.load(open('myfile.json'))

# raw_data contains a nested list, so convert it to a simple list :
data = [x[0] for x in raw_data]

# then create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

Here is the content of `data`. The nested list has been converted to a simple list (assuming that we have one record per array) :

```
[{"category": "VM1",
      "data": "9",
      "metric_name": "CPU",
      "time_stamp": "2019-03-28 13:15:31"},
     {"category": "VM1",
      "data": "9",
      "metric_name": "CPU",
      "time_stamp": "2019-03-28 13:15:31"}]
```

Comment: I am getting this error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: Try to replace `raw_data = json.load(open(file_path))` by `with open(file_path) as f: raw_data = json.loads(f.read())`

Comment: JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491420/python-jsonexpecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes