# Replace single quotes with double quotes but leave ones within double quotes untouched

Tags: python

The ultimate goal or the origin of the problem is to have a field compatible with in json_extract_path_text Redshift.

This is how it looks right now:

```py
{'error': "Feed load failed: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not object", 'errorCode': 3, 'event_origin': 'app', 'screen_id': '6118964227874465', 'screen_class': 'Promotion'}
```

To extract field I need from the string in Redshift, I replaced single quotes with double quotes.
The particular record is giving error because inside value of error, there is a single quote there. With that, the string will be a invalid json if those get replaced as well.

So what I need is:

```py
{"error": "Feed load failed: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not object", "errorCode": 3, "event_origin": "app", "screen_id": "6118964227874465", "screen_class": "Promotion"}
```

Comment: Did you try `json.dumps(d)`?

Answer (score 3):

I tried a regex approach but found it to complicated and slow. So i wrote a simple "bracket-parser" which keeps track of the current quotation mode. It can not do multiple nesting you'd need a stack for that. For my usecase converting str(dict) to proper JSON it works:

example input:
`{'cities': [{'name': "Upper Hell's Gate"}, {'name': "N'zeto"}]}`

example output:
`{"cities": [{"name": "Upper Hell's Gate"}, {"name": "N'zeto"}]}'`

**python unit test**

```py
def testSingleToDoubleQuote(self):
        jsonStr='''
        {
            "cities": [
            {
                "name": "Upper Hell's Gate"
            },
            {
                 "name": "N'zeto"
            }
            ]
        }
        '''
        listOfDicts=json.loads(jsonStr)
        dictStr=str(listOfDicts)   
        if self.debug:
            print(dictStr)
        jsonStr2=JSONAble.singleQuoteToDoubleQuote(dictStr)
        if self.debug:
            print(jsonStr2)
        self.assertEqual('''{"cities": [{"name": "Upper Hell's Gate"}, {"name": "N'zeto"}]}''',jsonStr2)
```

**singleQuoteToDoubleQuote**

```py
    def singleQuoteToDoubleQuote(singleQuoted):
            '''
            convert a single quoted string to a double quoted one
            Args:
                singleQuoted(string): a single quoted string e.g. {'cities': [{'name': "Upper Hell's Gate"}]}
            Returns:
                string: the double quoted version of the string e.g. 
            see
               - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600788/python-replace-single-quotes-with-double-quotes-but-leave-ones-within-double-q 
            '''
            cList=list(singleQuoted)
            inDouble=False;
            inSingle=False;
            for i,c in enumerate(cList):
                #print ("%d:%s %r %r" %(i,c,inSingle,inDouble))
                if c=="'":
                    if not inDouble:
                        inSingle=not inSingle
                        cList[i]='"'
                elif c=='"':
                    inDouble=not inDouble
            doubleQuoted="".join(cList)    
            return doubleQuoted
```

Comment: this will be problematic when a single quote is to be found inside single quotes. i.e.:
`"{'cities': [{'name': 'Upper Hell's Gate'}]"` => `'{"cities": [{"name": "Upper Hell"s Gate"}]'`.
also jsonStr in the unit test doesn't seem to go through any conversions there are no single quotes except inside double quotes. regex shouldn't be too slow, there are alternative pcre engines / languages if your use case vary.

Comment: single quotes in single quotes can't happen in my usecase it would be a syntax error for python and or JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways, one is to use the `regex` module with

```
"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|'
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lmxWvC/1/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\'')
new_string = rx.sub('"', old_string)
```

With the original `re` module, you'd need to use a function and see if the group has been matched or not - `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` lets you avoid exactly that.