# Covert String into list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I want to extract specific data from String of list of dictionaries but unable to do

I have performed json.loads operation but still getting error

```
import json
data =json.loads("[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Comment: This is not valid JSON. JSON uses "double quotes" not 'single quotes'

Comment: `json.loads("[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]".replace("'", "\""))`

Comment: Try to google error message first next time before creating new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491420/python-jsonexpecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes

Comment: I have already seen that question before posting the question. I have tried that method before posting question. That solution was not able to resolve error that's why I have posted this question

Answer (score 0):

change ' to "

```
import json
data =json.loads("[{\"id\": 35, \"name\": \"Comedy\"}]")
```

or

```
import json
data =json.loads('[{"id": 35, "name": "Comedy"}]')
```