# How to convert text file containing python dictionary into an actual one

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like so:

```
[{
"x": 0.37375009059906006,
"y": 0.858906626701355,
"y": 1.2558532880291295e-08,
},
{
"x": 0.4551462233066559,
"y": 0.8060519695281982,
"y": -0.023612480610609055,
},
{
"x": 0.5198760032653809,
"y": 0.7056148648262024,
"y": -0.0391654446721077,
},
etc, etc
```

And I want to know how to convert it into a proper list in python which stores the proper dictionaries.

My current code looks like this:

```
def create_array(type):
    path = f'data/hands/{type}'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    data = []
    for file in files:
        with open(f'{path}/{file}', 'r') as f:
            c_data = json.loads(f.read())
        data.append(c_data)
    data = [dict(x) for x in data]
    print(data)
```

But I'm just getting this error:

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 5 column 1 (Char 82)`

Anyone know how to get it working?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491420/python-jsonexpecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes) are a lot of answers, and solutions (even in the comments). I would suggest to take a look at them. (As we can't see the whole text, there is no way to tell if there is a comma at the end and so on)

Comment: Briefly this tells you there's something wrong with one or more syntax errors in your json files that you're attempting to load. Avoid using duplicate keys `y` too.

Comment: Replace `json.loads` with `yaml.loads` and it should just work without having to edit the file. Note: You have to add pyyaml dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are reading the file as JSON, you are getting an exception due to the `,` at the end of the last line on each dictionary (the second `"y"` value), so you have to remove these last extra commas. Like this:

```
[
    {
    "x": 0.37375009059906006,
    "y": 0.858906626701355,
    "y": 1.2558532880291295e-08
    },
    {
    "x": 0.4551462233066559,
    "y": 0.8060519695281982,
    "y": -0.023612480610609055
    },
    {
    "x": 0.5198760032653809,
    "y": 0.7056148648262024,
    "y": -0.0391654446721077
    }
]
```

Also, bear in mind that you are storing this data in dictionaries, so you should avoid repeating keys, otherwise, the duplicated ones will take the last value read. So I strongly recommend changing the last `"y"` on each dictionary to another key, e.g.: `"z"`.

Finally, your list `data` is not necessary as the `json.loads()` will return a list of dictionaries. Look at this simplified version of your code:

```
def create_array(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        c_data = json.loads(f.read())
    print(c_data)
```

This outputs:

```
[{'x': 0.37375009059906006, 'y': 1.2558532880291295e-08}, {'x': 0.4551462233066559, 'y': -0.023612480610609055}, {'x': 0.5198760032653809, 'y': -0.0391654446721077}]
```

Note how the values 0.858906626701355, 0.8060519695281982, and 0.7056148648262024 were replaced by 1.2558532880291295e-08, -0.023612480610609055, and -0.0391654446721077 respectively because of the duplicated key `"y"`.