# Parse Java Script in Python 3.6

Tags: javascript, python, parsing

I want to parse the following javascript which I scraped from an HTML page:

```
  var ibmdebug = false; //indicates whether or not to display flash debug window
  if (qsParse.get("debug") == "true") {
    ibmdebug = true;
  }
  var matchStatsConfig = {
    courtId : "B",
    matchId : "5126",

matchStatus : "C"
,
    eventId : "MX",
    roundId : "1",
    dayMessage : "Day 5 Friday 7 July",
    relatedContentTags :  ['atpi200','wta316629','atpba79','wta316713'],
    team1 : {
      a : "atpi200",
      a_name : "D. Inglot",
      a_seed : "",
      b : "wta316629",
      b_name : "L. Robson",
      b_seed : ""
    },
    team2 : {
      a : "atpba79",
      a_name : "A. Begemann",
      a_seed : "",
      b : "wta316713",
      b_name : "N. Melichar",
      b_seed : ""
    }
  }
```

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25112096/973158) I use the package slimit as follows where `js.text` contains the javascript code as a string:

```
data = js.text
parser = Parser()
tree = parser.parse(data)
fields = {getattr(node.left, 'value', ''): getattr(node.right, 'value', '')
for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree)
if isinstance(node, ast.Assign)}
print(fields)
```

The output/content of `fields` looks as follows

```
{
    'ibmdebug': 'true',
    'courtId': '"B"',
    'matchId': '"5126"',
    'matchStatus': '"C"',
    'eventId': '"MX"',
    'roundId': '"1"',
    'dayMessage': '"Day 5 Friday 7 July"',
    'relatedContentTags': '',
    'team1': '',
    'a': '"atpba79"',
    'a_name': '"A. Begemann"',
    'a_seed': '""',
    'b': '"wta316713"',
    'b_name': '"N. Melichar"',
    'b_seed': '""',
    'team2': ''
}
```

As you can see, it is not parsed correctly (only parts are correct). The array `relatedContentTags` remains empty, as do the `team1` and `team2` objects/dictionaries. Interestingly, the content of the `team2` variable is there. I assume this is the case because the content of `team1` is also parsed, but overwritten by the content of `team2`.

**My question is:** How can I properly parse the initial javascript into a python data structure (e.g. dictionary)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my javascript code did not use quotes for the keys it could only be parsed by demjson as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27155665/973158) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34812991/973158).

so my working code works as follows

```
# get only the "matchStatsConfig" variable
script = re.search(r'var matchStatsConfig = .*$', data, re.DOTALL).group()

# convert it to json
json = demjson.decode(script.replace('var matchStatsConfig =', ''))
```