# How to parse an unquoted json string to a dict in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing, quote

I have string in the format of:

```
'{comm:comm123,date: Aug 29, 2019 12:30:00 PM,value:qwert}'
```

I want to get something like this:

```
{
   'comm': 'comm123',
   'date': Aug 29, 2019 12:30:00 PM,   (As a date)
   'value': 'qwert'
}
```

I have tried using literal_eval and eval but they do not help. i also tried using json library but it does not seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: May be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34812991/6699447) help you

Comment: There is some ambiguity in the string, because date has commas and colons. '2019 12' seems a key in that string

Comment: Can you step back to before the string creation?

Comment: The string is stored in this format in a file. I am reading from that file and trying to parse it in the format shown.

Comment: Are the keys always the same and in that order? I have two ideas but need clarification.

Comment: If the keys are always the same length you can apply quotes based on position, that would help you to get some json

Comment: Other option is split by first and last comma, this will isolate the date pair so you can parse it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Your string is indeed ambiguous, however, you can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
d = '{comm:comm123,date: Aug 29, 2019 12:30:00 PM,value:qwert}'
new_d = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s\d{2},\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [APM]{2}|\w+', d)
result = {new_d[i]:new_d[i+1] for i in range(0, len(new_d), 2)}
```

Output:

```
{'comm': 'comm123', 'date': 'Aug 29, 2019 12:30:00 PM', 'value': 'qwert'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Horrible. The keys seem like they should be unambiguous though - if you know they are always alpha-only could extract them using something like `([a-zA-Z]+):`, then use that to get the "other" bits of the string which must be the values?