# How to get specific json value with regex

Tags: python, json, regex, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to figure out how to get the `"form:"` value from a html tag that looks like:

```
window.__webpack_public_path__='https://renderer-assets.helloWorld.com/';
window.__webpack_nonce__='ca0aa826f043cfc50cc24f6ae5a2fb4a';
window.rendererAssets='["https://renderer-assets.helloWorld.com/vendors~attachment~form-container.0ca60599ecb1b55e02bf.js","https://renderer-assets.helloWorld.com/vendors~libphonenumber~submission.7a28f3a3fe6660429a73.js","https://renderer-assets.helloWorld.com/country-data.62e9eca111db492e793d.js","https://renderer-assets.helloWorld.com/form-container.c34f13ff7b2a95addd81.js","https://renderer-assets.helloWorld.com/renderer.c8aaed3fb2c5d344f80d.js","https://renderer-assets.helloWorld.com/submission.a2f19d1069d330fd0866.js","https://renderer-assets.helloWorld.com/vendors~form-container.9853dbb220cd33f30c2f.js"]';
window.rendererData= {
    scriptSrc: 'https://renderer-assets.helloworld.com/renderer.c8aaed3fb2c5d344f80d.js',
    rootDomNode: 'root',
    form: {
        "id":"Z3PvTW",
        "title":"TESTING",
        "theme": {
            "id":"xwizbR",
            "font":"Oswald",
            "name":"Plain Blue (copy)",
            "colors": {
                "question": "#3D3D3D", "answer": "#000000", "button": "#000000", "background": "#FFFFFF"
            }
            ,
            "has_transparent_button":false,
            "visibility":"private"
        }
        ,
        "workspace": {
            "href": "https:\u002F\u002Fapi.helloWorld.com\u002Fworkspaces\u002FnutqqY"
        }
        ,
        "settings": {
            "is_public":true,
            "is_trial":false,
            "language":"en",
            "progress_bar":"proportion",
            "show_progress_bar":true,
            "show_helloWorld_branding":true,
            "meta": {
                "allow_indexing": false
            }
        }
        ,
        "welcome_screens":[ {
            "ref":"a13820db-af60-40eb-823d-86cf0f20299b",
            "title":"TESTING VALUES",
            "properties": {
                "show_button": true, "button_text": "Start"
            }
        }
        ],
        "thankyou_screens":[ {
            "ref":"default_tys",
            "title":"Done! Your information was sent perfectly.",
            "properties": {
                "show_button": false, "share_icons": false
            }
        }
        ],
        "fields":[ {
            "id":"kxWycKljdtBq",
            "title":"FIRST NAME",
            "ref":"27f403f7-8c5b-4e18-b19d-1501e8f137ee",
            "validations": {
                "required": true
            }
            ,
            "type":"short_text"
        },
        {
            "id":"WEXCnZ7EAFjN",
            "title":"LAST NAME",
            "ref":"a6bf6d83-ee37-4870-b6c5-779822290cde",
            "validations": {
                "required": true
            }
            ,
            "type":"short_text"
        }

        ],
        "_links": {
            "display": "https:\u002F\u002Fautosnkr.helloWorld.com\u002Fto\u002FZ3PvTW"
        }
    }
    ,
    trackingInfo: {
        "segmentKey": "9at6spGDYXelHDdz4r0cP73b3wV1f0ri", "accountId": 12587347, "accountLimitName": "Essentials", "userId": 12586030
    }
```

My point here is to be able to get the whole form: value into a json.loads where I can later on modify it the way I want to do but before that I need to be able to get the `form:` value and what I have tried to do is following:

```
regexTest = re.compile(r'form:\((.*?)\);', re.DOTALL)
data = regexTest.findall(response.text)
```

which just returned `[]`

My question is, how am I able to get the whole `form:` json value into a `getAllForm = json.loads(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
match = re.search(r"form: ({(\s+.*){1,}\})", response.text).group(1)
print(match)
```

Output:

```
{
        "id":"Z3PvTW",
        "title":"TESTING",
        "theme": {
            "id":"xwizbR",
            "font":"Oswald",
            "name":"Plain Blue (copy)",
            "colors": {
                "question": "#3D3D3D", "answer": "#000000", "button": "#000000", "background": "#FFFFFF"
            }
            ,
            "has_transparent_button":false,
            "visibility":"private"
        }
        ,
        "workspace": {
            "href": "https://api.helloWorld.com/workspaces/nutqqY"
        }
        ,
        "settings": {
            "is_public":true,
            "is_trial":false,
            "language":"en",
            "progress_bar":"proportion",
            "show_progress_bar":true,
            "show_helloWorld_branding":true,
            "meta": {
                "allow_indexing": false
            }
        }
        ,
        "welcome_screens":[ {
            "ref":"a13820db-af60-40eb-823d-86cf0f20299b",
            "title":"TESTING VALUES",
            "properties": {
                "show_button": true, "button_text": "Start"
            }
        }
        ],
        "thankyou_screens":[ {
            "ref":"default_tys",
            "title":"Done! Your information was sent perfectly.",
            "properties": {
                "show_button": false, "share_icons": false
            }
        }
        ],
        "fields":[ {
            "id":"kxWycKljdtBq",
            "title":"FIRST NAME",
            "ref":"27f403f7-8c5b-4e18-b19d-1501e8f137ee",
            "validations": {
                "required": true
            }
            ,
            "type":"short_text"
        },
        {
            "id":"WEXCnZ7EAFjN",
            "title":"LAST NAME",
            "ref":"a6bf6d83-ee37-4870-b6c5-779822290cde",
            "validations": {
                "required": true
            }
            ,
            "type":"short_text"
        }

        ],
        "_links": {
            "display": "https://autosnkr.helloWorld.com/to/Z3PvTW"
        }
    }
    ,
    trackingInfo: {
        "segmentKey": "9at6spGDYXelHDdz4r0cP73b3wV1f0ri", "accountId": 12587347, "accountLimitName": "Essentials", "userId": 12586030
    }
```

Now regarding loading your `JSONP` dict into valid `JSON` dict.

Check that `key` which is `trackingInfo`, it's actually missing `trackingInfo` to be as `"trackingInfo"`. So you need to quote it, Since this will be count as a duplicate. Please check [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812821/python-bad-json-keys-are-not-quoted)

Comment: I used this help and it actually helped me :D Apprecaite it!